# Eclipse CDT "step into" doesn't work

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt

I set up a breakpoint, and when I run the program in debug mode, and click "step into" when it reaches that breakpoint, it doesn't step into it.

Why?

EDIT:
I'm compiling with these flags:

> -Wall -pedantic -pedantic-errors -Wunused -Wunreachable-code -g -ggdb

EDIT 2:
When I turn on the `instruction stepping mode` and immediately afterwards step into the function that I marked with a breakpoint, **and then repeatedly call "step into"**, I get this:

```
No source available for "Indexer::index() at 0x8054de6"
```

Comment: Care to elaborate a bit? Are you compiling it with debugging symbols, optimization, etc?

Comment: @l19 "It works for me" is an appropriate answer for this question as you have given us so little to go on. It could be that you are throwing an exception at the point you are about to step into he function. Are you able to step over?

Comment: @Dennis, yes. Please let me know what information you need to help me. Thanks!

Comment: Anyone? Help!!! I need the debugger to work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, there was a problem with my `makefile`...

I was missing this:

```
%.o: %.cpp %.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<
```

Comment: You should let people know how you did it in case they are looking at a similar issue.

Comment: @I19 : Hi, I am encountering the same problem. Could you explain your solution so that I could learn and apply to my code? Thanks so much.

Comment: @user2751691 i think you're better off creating a new question

Comment: @I19 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572335/eclipse-cdt-cannot-debug-to-step-into-function-definition-in-same-directory I created this one but the solution provided did not work.

Comment: @I19 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614280/eclipse-cdt-cannot-step-into-functions-in-other-files          I made the question more clear. Please help to take a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your debugger cannot find the source for the code you are debugging. You should be able to debug it as assembler though. In order to fix the problem I would suggest that you find the source code for Indexer and make sure that your code paths are correctly set.

Comment: What do you mean by "make sure that your code paths are correctly set"?